# TestFlight is not Symbolicating my iOS crash report properly

Tags: ios, crash-reports, testflight, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I've uploaded my IPA and .dSYM file on test flight. .dSYM file uploaded  and attached successfully. My client tested the app and it crashed. Crash report is shown in TestFlight Crash Section. But the problem is that, TestFlight is not symbolicating the report properly. The report only displays 0x numbers, but no reference to any class or method. 
The report is given below: 
[image: TestFlight Crash Report]

Can you tell me where is the problem? Or, how can I decode this crash report's line # 0 from my computer?

Comment: How about contacting testflight support?

Comment: I've already contacted them. But didn't receive any response yet.

Comment: Have you tried to symbolicate yourself, you've told you've got the dSYM and the crash!?

try to use f.e. this http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/

Comment: I've contacted TestFlight and they fixed this problem. The problem was on their side.